# Can you pause cutscenes in Hogwarts Legacy?

Tags: hogwarts-legacy

Is there a way to pause cutscenes in Hogwarts Legacy?

Sometimes I need to urgently go and do other things while a cutscene is running and I can't find a way to pause the cutscenes. I can only leave it running or skip the cutscene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, there’s no in-game method to pause a cutscene in Hogwarts Legacy. The only interaction you can make during cutscenes is choosing to skip them by holding a button (either Triangle on PlayStation, Y  on Xbox, or right-click on PC mouse and keyboard). Some good news is that most platforms have workarounds, though not all.

### How to Pause Cutscenes on Consoles

Console players can force Hogwarts Legacy to pause by going into the Home menus for their respective platforms. On Xbox Series X|S, pressing or holding the Xbox button should be sufficient. When it comes to the PS5, pressing a button isn’t enough; the cutscene will continue to play in the background. Players will have to hold the PS Button to forcibly pause Hogwarts Legacy.

### How to Pause Cutscenes on PC

The PC platform is the only one that doesn’t have a workaround for pausing. Alt-tabbing or minimizing the window has no effect. Once a cutscene starts, PC players are expected to sit down and enjoy the show until they can take a break.

But... there is some good news. Modders have already come to the rescue on PC and gave us a mod to pause cutscenes. The mod is called "Game Pauser" and you can find it on [nexusmods](https://www.nexusmods.com/hogwartslegacy/mods/125).

---

Let's hope in the future that they bring this natively into the game. We really need a way to easily pause during cutscenes.

Comment: In my experience there are very few games that have this functionality. You can *skip* cut-scenes in a lot of games, very few don't allow this - but I've only experienced a handful of games that allow you to pause cut-scenes.